# Extract all folders from NSUrl

Tags: objective-c, directory, extract, nsurl

I have following NSURL, and would need to split it into its various components:

- The FTP-Url,
- Each of the folders in order to be able to iterate through them.

What is the best way to do this? I know i can use `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` but i would like to be sure that it is the BEST way to do it and that there isnt already a function provided to do just that. (like for example to extract the filename from the NSURL)

```
 NSURL *url;
 url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlText];  //urlText is ftp.somesite.com/folder1/folder2/folder3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a built in way to access it, using the `pathComponents` property:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://ftp.somesite.com/folder1/folder2/folder3"];
NSArray *pathComponents = url.pathComponents;
NSLog(@"%@", pathComponents); // ( @"folder1", @"folder2", @"folder3" )
```

This is definitely the best approach, since it will handle URL escaping and all that for you.

Comment: thank you very much! will accept in 10 minutes as soon as the site lets me do it!

Comment: sorry but how to extract the site alone? i mean the url of the FTP? thanks

Comment: @user2452250: I would suggest that you have a look at the "Accessing the Parts of the URL" section of the [NSURL documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It's all there.

Comment: thanks @MartinR i already had a look there and tried BaseUrl and Host but none of them worked.. they both returned (Null)

Comment: @user2452250: With `url` as in this answer,  `[url scheme]` returns "ftp" and `[url host]` returns "ftp.somesite.com" ...

Comment: @user2452250 are you sure the `url` is not `null`? That will cause scheme/host/etc to also be `null`. It's one of the unique things about Obj-C.

Comment: solved! i had to add ftp:// in front of the url. without ftp:// it doesnt work and returns null! thanks guys